# How to get response from google share api.?

Tags: google-plus

I am using a google+ share button. It is working fine and content is also shared successfully. But I want to generate notification on successful share and the same for error.
For that I need response of google+ share. If anyone have idea how to get response from google+ share api, Please share. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google+ Share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share) does not offer a mechanism for detecting the sharing of a post for the web. The `onstartinteraction` and `onendinteraction` parameters are triggered on the hover events in case you need to listen to those for other events.

The [+1 button does offer a callback](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#attr-callback) but that isn't used for detecting a share from the button but rather a +1. Also, you need to be careful to ensure that you follow the [Google+ button policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy).

Comment: But there should be some other way to use google+ share api to get response. And also do you have any idea to get response from twitter share api?? Thanks BrettJ for your help..

Comment: Maybe it would help to understand what your app is trying to accomplish. You didn't say if it was a mobile or web app. Can you elaborate on your app and goal in your original question?